# Hive Join Error

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I'm running a simple query in hive based and am getting the error:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/hadoop/bin/hadoop" (in directory "/home/ec2-user"): error=13, Permission denied

When I do a simple select,

```
 select * from million_songs_sample;
```

it works just fine.  But when I incorporate the join is when I get the error.

Here is my code which is causing the error:

```
 SELECT a.song as driver_song_id, b.song as also_song_id,
 count(a.play_count) as play_count
 from (
 select user, song, play_count
 from million_songs_sample) a 
 join (
 select user, song
 from million_songs_sample) b 
 on a.user = b.user
 where a.song != b.song
 group by a.song, b.song;
 group by a.song, b.user;
```

Here is the data in my table:

```
 u1,s10,3
 u1,s11,1
 u1,s15,5
 u1,s17,1
 u1,s19,3
 u2,s10,1
 u2,s12,6
 u2,s19,5
 u3,s11,1
 u3,s12,1
 u3,s13,1
 u3,s14,1
 u3,s17,3
 u4,s10,2
 u4,s12,5
 u4,s19,3
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like some sort of permissions issue on temporary tables -- you will need to talk to local people to figure that out.

However, perhaps rewriting the query without the subqueries will fix the problem:

```
SELECT a.song as driver_song_id, b.song as also_song_id,
       count(a.play_count) as play_count
from million_songs_sample a join
     million_songs_sample b 
     on a.user = b.user
where a.song <> b.song
group by a.song, b.song;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot join a table on itself when creating the table from S3 storage.  To get around that, first create a TEMP table as a copy of the second join, and it works well.